# How do I find the right selector when scraping a website with jSoup?

Tags: python, java, web-scraping, netbeans, jsoup

I am currently learning how to web scrape and am using jSoup to do so. I read the jSoup cookbook on how to do so and followed it's steps. I made sure the source code for the website prints, making sure that is working and is correct. But when I have to find a selector for looping through a websites table, I don't know what to look for, or what to select. I will leave my code below, though I just would like to know what to look for.

```
    String url = "https://www.centralcharts.com/en/price-list-ranking/ALL/asc/ts_29-us-nyse-stocks--qc_1-alphabetical-order";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Jsoup Scraper").get();

    String stock = "tr:nth-of-type(1) > .footable-first-visible";
    Elements stockName = doc.select(stock);
    List<String> stocks = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Element e : stockName) 
    {
        stocks.add(e.text());
    }

    for (String s : stocks) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```